# Jersey client send string with application/json type

Tags: java, json, jersey, genson

I need to send a String that is already in `JSON` format using the `Jersey client 1.19` and `genson 1.3`

```
Client.create().resource(path).webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).put(ClientResponse.class, jsonAsString)
```

The problem with this is that the client is parsing the string, I need it to be sent as it is.
I'm sending something like `{ "name":"Foo" }` and the client is converting it to `"{ \"name\":\"Foo\" }"`. If I change the type to `PLAIN_TEXT` it sends the request correctly but I need to send it as `application/json` .

Comment: When you say the client is converting where are you seeing the conversion? On the server?

Comment: I'm sniffing it with wireshark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So yes Genson will try to encode your string as a literal json string. In this case it is maybe not what you would want, but more generally it is what people would expect: serialize à java string as a json string.

The solution I see is too extend [GensonJsonConverter](https://github.com/owlike/genson/blob/master/genson/src/main/java/com/owlike/genson/ext/jaxrs/GensonJsonConverter.java) and override isWritable to return false when the input type is string. Then just register it. That should work.

I've opened [this issue](https://github.com/owlike/genson/issues/73) so it can be added as a more flexible feature.

Comment: Wouldn't a standalone literal JSON string always be invalid JSON? It should be a JSON object or JSON array right? So if type is "application/json" and data is of type `String` wouldn't it be better to always send as is? I haven't seen Genson code but I meant when it is being intercepted upon a `post()` or `put()`.

Comment: There is an updated version for json spec that allows any kind of value as root element, not only object and array. Have a look at the issue for an updated solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE` to `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` 
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/

Comment: Im getting the same behavior with MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with Jersey 1.19, Genson 1.3 and Wireshark. It works fine without Genson so it appears Genson is treating it as a literal string (since it is of type `String`) and therefore quoting the double quotes.

The following works.

```
    String jsonAsString = "{ \"name\":\"Foo\" }";
    Map<String, String> map = (new Genson()).deserialize(jsonAsString, Map.class);
    String path = "...";
    ClientResponse resp = 
            Client.create().resource(path)
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .put(ClientResponse.class, map);
```

I have used Map because it is sufficient for the example but you can deserialize it to the appropriate object.

If you looking for an option to specify that the string should be passed as is, I am not yet aware of it but this should at least provide a solution to the problem of sending that string as application/json.